# AEM and jQuery:: Code working in MS edge but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, aem

This is the code I have written and it is working very inconsistently. It works on Microsoft edge but not on Chrome. It uses bootstrap framework to popup a modal box.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="cnbModalPopUpRedirect-disclosure1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="cnbModalPopUpRedirectLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title" id="cnbModalPopUpRedirectLabel">
                        You are about to leave the City National Bank website.
                    </h3>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;
                      </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>The website you are about to enter is not operated by City National Bank. City National Bank does not endorse the content of this website and makes no warranty as the accuracy of content or functionality of this website. City National Bank is not responseible for the security, content or availability of any third-party sites, or their partners. The terms of use, privacy and security policies of the site may differ from those of City National Bank.</p>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a data-title="modal-cnb-redirect" class="btn btn-primary btn-modal" href="http://hudlinentertainment.com/" role="button" target="_blank">
                        Continue
                    </a>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                            Close
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/utils.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/jquery/granite.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc.clientlibs/news-and-insights/components/content/disclosure/clientlibs.min.js"></script>
```

The boostrap js is also being included in the footer of the page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc.clientlibs/news-and-insights/clientlibs/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The javascript I have written to handle to handle the click event (in the file /etc.clientlibs/news-and-insights/components/content/disclosure/clientlibs.min.js):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href*="#disclosure"]').click(function(e) {
         console.log('---inside code------');
        var nodeName = e.target.nodeName;
         console.log('---inside code nodeName------'+nodeName);
        if(nodeName) {
            if(nodeName === 'A') {
                console.log('---inside A------');
            var href = $(e.target).attr('href');
                if (href !== undefined && href!=null) {
                href = href.substr(1);
                console.log('---insidehref------'+href);
                var modalId = "#cnbModalPopUpRedirect-"+href;
                console.log('---insidemodalId------'+modalId);
                $(modalId).modal();
                }
            }
        }
            });
  });
```

I looked at the debug console too but it is not throwing any error and  console.log inside `$('a[href*="#disclosure"]').click(function(e) {` is not getting printed either in the debugger console. I don't know if there is something about the chrome browser that doesn't like the code or if the code itself is not written how it should have been.

EDIT::

This is the HTML:

```
<p>Participants include: Reginald Hudlin, CEO of&nbsp;
    <a href="#disclosure1">
        Hudlin Entertainment
    </a>; 
    Jennifer Houston, managing partner at Makai; 
    Kim Watson, president and co-founder of Groupie Inc.; 
    Mike Cano, CEO of&nbsp;
    <a href="http://www.latinodigitalsolutions.com/" target="_blank">
        Latino Digital Solutions
    </a>; 
    and Allison Samuels,&nbsp;
    <a href="https://www.harpercollins.com/cr-110001/allison-samuels" target="_blank">
        author and journalist
    </a>.
</p>
```

Also this piece of HTML is above any other code I have written

Comment: I only see one `<a>` tag in the HTML you posted, and it's `href` attribute does not include the string "#disclosure". If jQuery finds no elements from a selector, you will not get an error. I have no idea why Edge would find the element however.

Comment: My apologies. I have updated the post with the HTML code.

Comment: I'm assuming #cnbModalPopUpRedirect-disclosure1 exists on the page somewhere.  I don't see a problem with your Javascript.  However, Testing my own function in any Chrome console instance: $(document).click(function(e){ console.log(e.target.nodeName);console.log($(e.target).attr('class'));}) I get expected outputs like DIV, row and so on.  (edited - I see where you have your script plugged in)

Comment: Is the bottom HTML fragment on the same page with the script tag that calls the Javascript function?

Comment: When is the HTML that you added (that includes the `<a href="#disclosure1">`) to the page?  Is it dynamically added?  If that element doesn't exist whenever the `$().ready` runs, it won't bind.  Put a break point in the ready handler and search in the DOM manually using your inspector tools for that exact element.  If it doesn't exist then, that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make absolutely sure that the HTML segment you are querying exists in the DOM **before** you actually query for it.  If it is dynamically added and that element doesn't exist whenever the `$().ready` runs, it won't bind.  Put a break point in the ready handler and search in the DOM manually using your inspector tools for that exact element.  If it doesn't exist then, that's the issue.

Consider this example that demonstrates 2 anchors, both of which will satisfy your selector, but only the one that exists in the DOM before the query works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href*="#disclosure"]').click(function(e) {
    console.log("Foo");
  });

  // Alternatively, you can delegate to account for dynamic content
  $(document).on("click", 'a[href*="#disclosure"]', function(e) {
    // This console will print for both anchors
    console.log("Bar");
  });
});

$(function() {
  // This one doesn't exist until after and thus, won't work
  $("#foo").append($("<a></a>", {
    href: "#disclosure2",
    text: "Disclosure 2"
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="foo">
  <!-- This anchor exists before the query happens -->
  <a href="#disclosure1">Disclosure 1</a>
</div>
```